# Trigger geocoding without having to visit page

Tags: javascript, google, php, mysql, google-maps-api

I'm using Google's geocoder to store results in database then display them on a map on another page. The problem is that each company profile page needs to be visited before it's geocoded.

Is there a way to run the geocoder if a company address's lat/lng is 0 (i.e it hasn't been geocoded)?

```
<?php 

require("database.php");
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("medicom_wp", $con);


    $company = get_field('company_name');
    $address = get_field('address');
    $city = get_field('city');
    $post_code = get_field('post_code');

    $sql = sprintf("select count('x') as cnt from markers where `name` = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($company));
    $row_dup = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql,$con));
    if ($row_dup['cnt'] == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`) VALUES ('".$company."', '".$address.", ".$city.", ".$post_code."', '0.0', '0.0', '')");
}
wp_reset_query();


define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
define("KEY", "");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;

// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $geocode_pending = true;

  while ($geocode_pending) {
    $address = $row["address"];
    $id = $row["id"];
    $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

    $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
      // Successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
      $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
      // Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
      $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
      $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];

      $query = sprintf("UPDATE markers " .
             " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
             " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
      $update_result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$update_result) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
      }
    } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
      // sent geocodes too fast
      $delay += 1000;
    } else {
      // failure to geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
      echo "Received status " . $status . "
\n";
    }
    usleep($delay);
  }
}


?>
```

Before anyone says, I actually followed a tutorial from Google themselves saying how to store geocode results in a database, so in my eyes it doesn't go against their TOS because they're telling you to do it!

Comment: If you have the address stored you can bulk geocode the business address. TOS as long as your 'map' is a Google map you can store geocodes in a db. http://batchgeo.com/ does this

Comment: @Mapperz Because the data is entered via Wordpress and can change or be added to at any time the process needs to be automatic not manual.

Comment: you can use a MySQL trigger - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html when that is fired a geocode request is sent out and waits a response - if vaild then is stored in your db.

Answer (score 1):

You can use most of this code on this Tutorial Site:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/interactive-travel-map-google-maps-api/

replacing the 'manual' intervention with a trigger in mysql when your wordpress is updated.

This will then geocode the new entry and store it back in the MySQL database.

The Official Tutorial only geocodes once - the mysql trigger will keep it up-to-date
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode

Trigger solution - all this needs modifying to suite your needs
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/329172/grrr...-new-trigger-problem